# Unable to set PATH using SetEnvironmentVariable

Tags: powershell, rabbitmq, erlang

I am trying to set the environment variable in my powershell script.

Heres my code snippet.It sets the system environment variable (System Properties > Environment variable > Path) however, I am unable to start rabbitmq-service in powershell.

'$ENV:PATH' command output doesn't have the newly added path. After system restart $ENV:PATH contains the new path but the command 'rabbitmq-service' still doesnt work.

```
  # SET Erlang and RabbitMQ  Home Path
    $ERLANG_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\erl9.2"
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ERLANG_HOME", $ERLANG_HOME, "Machine")

    $ERTS_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\erts-9.2"
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ERTS_HOME", $ERTS_HOME, "Machine")

    $RABBITMQ_HOME = "$env:PROGRAMFILES\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.11" 
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("RABBITMQ_HOME", $RABBITMQ_HOME, "Machine")


    # Add Erlang and RabbitMQ to Path     
    $System_Path_Elems = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "Machine").Split(";")
    if (!$System_Path_Elems.Contains("$RABBITMQ_HOME\sbin") -and !$System_Path_Elems.Contains("$ERLANG_HOME\bin") -and !$System_Path_Elems.Contains("$ERTS_HOME\bin"))
    {       
    $newPath = [System.String]::Join(";", $System_Path_Elems + "$ERLANG_HOME\bin" + "$ERTS_HOME\bin" + "$RABBITMQ_HOME\sbin")
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $newPath, "Machine")   
    }
```

If I set the PATH using $env:PATH as below in my script, It works.

```
$env:Path += ";C:\\Program Files\\erl9.2\\erts-9.2\\bin;
C:\\Program Files\\RabbitMQ Server\\rabbitmq_server-3.6.11\\sbin;C:\\Program Files\\erl9.2\\bin"
```

I am able to execute the following commands without any issues.

```
rabbitmq-service remove
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management --offline
rabbitmq-service install
rabbitmq-service start
```

So, why 'SetEnvironmentVariable' doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: the method you are calling changes the top level environment ... but it _does not change the current PoSh environment_. [*grin*] the change you made with that method will be available in the next PoSh session you start.

Comment: Can you provide us with the output of your $env:PATH after you run the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$env:PATH = ...
```

is equivalent to (namespace prefix `System.` implied):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
  'PATH', 
   ..., 
   [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process
)
```

<sup>PowerShell automatically converts strings to enumeration values, so `'Process'` in lieu of `[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process` works too.</sup>

That is, in both cases you're **updating the environment variable for the *current process only*** - future sessions will *not* see the updated value.

By contrast, if you use [`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable#System_Environment_SetEnvironmentVariable_System_String_System_String_System_EnvironmentVariableTarget_) with the **`[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine` / `[EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User`** targets, you **update the *persistent* definitions** machine-wide / for the current user only, *without also updating the value in the current process*; that is, these definitions **only take effect in *future* sessions.**

Unfortunately, there is no *single* call that would allow you to do *both*, so you'll need *two* calls:

```
# Update the current process' env.var
$env.PATH = ... 
# Also persist the new value.
# Note that targeting [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine requires
# ELEVATION (running as admin).
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, <target>)
```

**Caveat**:

- On Windows, the process-level `$env:PATH` value is a *composite* value, the concatenation of the registry-based *machine*-level and the *user*-level definitions.
- Additionally, just as `$env:PATH` only contains *expanded*, literal values - even though he underlying registry entries may be defined by incorporating references to *other* environment variables (e.g. `%SystemRoot%`) - `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` only supports writing *literal* paths.

A proper solution therefore requires reading and writing raw (unresolved) definitions from the registry, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375).