# Adding path permanently to windows using powershell doesn't appear to work

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables

I followed [this procedure](https://codingbee.net/powershell/powershell-make-a-permanent-change-to-the-path-environment-variable) in order to permanently add a path to SumatraPDF using powershell. The last few commands from the link are meant to check that the path has indeed been added.

When I access the path using the following command,

```
(get-itemproperty -path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path.split(';')
```

the result includes the path to SumatraPDF

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32
C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF
```

However when I access it using the following command,

```
($env:path).split(';')
```

the result does not contain the path to SumatraPDF:

```
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\texlive\2021\bin\win32
C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
```

Finally, actually passing `sumatrapdf` does not works, which indicates to me that the real path is the one accessed using the `get-itemproperty` command.

Why does the path set in the registry not correspond to the one set in `$env:path`? Is there a mistake in the procedure shown in the [link](https://codingbee.net/powershell/powershell-make-a-permanent-change-to-the-path-environment-variable) I followed? How can I correct it?

I should mention I have already tried restarting the shell but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Preface**:

- See the middle section for **helper function `Add-Path`**
- See the bottom section for why use of **`setx.exe` should be avoided** for updating the **`Path` environment variable**.

---

The **procedure in the [linked blog post](https://codingbee.net/powershell/powershell-make-a-permanent-change-to-the-path-environment-variable) is effective *in principle*, but is missing a crucial piece of information / additional step**:

**If you modify environment variables directly *via the registry*** - which, unfortunately, **is the *right* way to do it for `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-based environment variables such as `Path`** - **you need to broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message** so that the [Windows (GUI) shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell) (and its components, File Explorer, the taskbar, the desktop, the Start Menu, all provided via `explorer.exe` processes) is notified of the environment change and *reloads* its environment variables from the registry. Applications launched afterwards then inherit the updated environment.

- If this message is *not* sent, future PowerShell sessions (and other applications) won't see the modification until the next logon / reboot.

Unfortunately, there's **no direct way to do this from PowerShell**, but there are **workarounds**:

- **Brute-force** workaround - simple, but **visually disruptive and closes all open File Explorer windows**:

  ```bash
  # Kills all explorer.exe processes, which restarts the Windows shell
  # components, forcing a reload of the environment from the registry.
  Stop-Process -Name explorer
  ```
- Workaround via **.NET APIs**:

  ```bash
  # Create a random name assumed to be unique
  [string] $dummyName = New-Guid
  # Set an environment variable by that name, which makes .NET
  # send a WM_SETTINGCHANGE broadcast
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyName, 'foo', 'User')
  # Now that the dummy variable has served its purpose, remove it again.
  # (This will trigger another broadcast, but its performance impact is negligible.)
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyName, [NullString]::value, 'User')
  ```

  - Note: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76876384/45375) explains why **using `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` to *directly* update the `PATH` variable is *not* a proper solution** as of .NET 8 - though you may get away with it.
- Workaround by **calling the Windows API** via an ad hoc-compiled P/Invoke call to `SendMessageTimeout()` in C#, via [`Add-Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type):

  - While this is a proper solution, it **invariably incurs a noticeable performance penalty** due to the ad hoc-compilation the first time it is run in a session.
  - For details, see [this blog post](https://www.angryadmin.co.uk/?tag=wm_settingchange).

The approach in the blog post mentioned in the question has **another problematic aspect**:

- It **retrieves the *expanded* environment-variable value from the registry, because that is what [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) and [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) invariably do**. That is, if directories in the value are defined in terms of *other environment variables* (e.g., `%SystemRoot%` or `%JAVADIR%`), the returned value no longer contains these variables, but their *current values*. See the bottom section for why this can be problematic.

The helper function discussed in the next section addresses all  issues, while also ensuring that the modification takes effect for the *current session* too.

---

The following **`Add-Path` helper function**:

- Adds (appends) a given, single directory path to the persistent *user-level* `Path` environment variable by default; use `-Scope Machine` to target the *machine-level* definition, which requires *elevation* (run as admin).

  - If the directory is already present in the target variable, no action is taken.
  - The relevant registry value is *updated*, which preserves its `REG_EXPAND_SZ` data type, based on the existing *unexpanded* value -  that is, references to other environment variables are preserved as such (e.g., `%SystemRoot%`), and may also be used in the new entry being added.
- Triggers a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message broadcast to inform the Windows shell of the change.
- Also updates the *current session's* `$env:Path` variable value.
- It is unfortunate that PowerShell doesn't ship with this functionality; a previous discussion about providing a cmdlet for robustly and selectively updating `$env:PATH` has gone nowhere - see the abandoned [GitHub RFC #92](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/92#issuecomment-429451171) (which covered providing cmdlets for managing persistent environment variables in general).<sup>[1]</sup>

Note: By definition (due to use of the registry), this function is *Windows-only*.

With the function below defined, your desired `Path` addition could be performed as follows, modifying the *current user's* persistent `Path` definition:

```bash
Add-Path C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF
```

If you really want to update the *machine-level* definition (in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` registry hive, which doesn't make sense with a *user-specific path*), add `-Scope Machine`, but not that you must then run *with elevation* (as admin).

**`Add-Path` source code**:

```bash
function Add-Path {

  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position=0)]
    [string] $LiteralPath,
    [ValidateSet('User', 'CurrentUser', 'Machine', 'LocalMachine')]
    [string] $Scope 
  )

  Set-StrictMode -Version 1; $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  $isMachineLevel = $Scope -in 'Machine', 'LocalMachine'
  if ($isMachineLevel -and -not $($ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'; net session 2>$null)) { throw "You must run AS ADMIN to update the machine-level Path environment variable." }  

  $regPath = 'registry::' + ('HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment')[$isMachineLevel]

  # Note the use of the .GetValue() method to ensure that the *unexpanded* value is returned.
  $currDirs = (Get-Item -LiteralPath $regPath).GetValue('Path', '', 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames') -split ';' -ne ''

  if ($LiteralPath -in $currDirs) {
    Write-Verbose "Already present in the persistent $(('user', 'machine')[$isMachineLevel])-level Path: $LiteralPath"
    return
  }

  $newValue = ($currDirs + $LiteralPath) -join ';'

  # Update the registry.
  Set-ItemProperty -Type ExpandString -LiteralPath $regPath Path $newValue

  # Broadcast WM_SETTINGCHANGE to get the Windows shell to reload the
  # updated environment, via a dummy [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable() operation.
  $dummyName = [guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyName, 'foo', 'User')
  [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyName, [NullString]::value, 'User')

  # Finally, also update the current session's `$env:Path` definition.
  # Note: For simplicity, we always append to the in-process *composite* value,
  #        even though for a -Scope Machine update this isn't strictly the same.
  $env:Path = ($env:Path -replace ';$') + ';' + $LiteralPath

  Write-Verbose "`"$LiteralPath`" successfully appended to the persistent $(('user', 'machine')[$isMachineLevel])-level Path and also the current-process value."

}
```

---

##### The limitations of [`setx.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) and why it shouldn't be used to update the `Path` environment variable:

`setx.exe` has fundamental limitations that make it problematic, particularly for updating environment variables that are based on `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-typed registry values, such as `Path`:

- Values are **limited to 1024 characters**, with additional ones getting *truncated*, albeit with a *warning* (as of at least Windows 10).
- The environment variable that is **(re)created is with type `REG_SZ` *if the new value happens NOT to contain environment-variable references such as `%SystemRoot%`***.<sup>[2]</sup> However, `Path` is originally of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ` and indeed contains directory paths based on *other* environment variables, such as `%SystemRoot%` and `%JAVADIR%`.

  - If the new value contains only *literal* paths (no environment-variable references) that may have no *immediate* ill effects, but, for an instance, an entry that originally depended on `%JAVADIR%` will stop working if the value of `%JAVADIR%` is later changed. Similarly, if you later add an entry that is expressed in terms of other environment-variables, such entries will *not* be expanded.
- Additionally, if you base the updated value on the current session's `$env:Path` value, you'll end up *duplicating* entries, because the *process-level* `$env:Path` value is a *composite* of the machine-level and current-user-level values.

  - This increases the risk of running into the 1024-character limit, especially if the technique is used *repeatedly*. It also bears the risk of duplicate values *lingering* after the original entry is removed from the original scope.
  - While you can avoid this particular problem by retrieving the scope-specific value either directly from the registry or - invariably in *expanded* form - via `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')` or `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine')`, that still doesn't solve the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` problem discussed above.

---

<sup>[1] A [prototype implementation](https://github.com/JamesWTruher/EnvironmentVariableModule) of new cmdlets for managing persistent environment variables is available via the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/EnvironmentVariableCmdlet/), though it seems to languish and, crucially, lacks support for *expandable* environment variables (`REG_EXPAND_SZ`) as of this writing, which makes it unsuitable for `PATH` updates.</sup>

<sup>[2] That is, `setx.exe` decides whether to (re)create the underlying registry value as `REG_SZ` (static) or `REG_EXPAND_SZ` purely based on the presence of environment-variable references such as `%SystemRoot%` in the *new* value - irrespective of a preexisting registry value's current type.</sup>

Comment: I suggest you guys add this function as standard into powershell. I doesn't make sense that we should have to think about all this under-the-hood trickery, to perform a simple add to the user or system paths. (Anything preventing *you* from doing this?)

Comment: @not2qubit, I fully agree, but, unfortunately, a previous discussion has gone nowhere, and I have no say in what does and doesn't get added to PowerShell itself (whereas everyone is free to contribute install-on-demand modules via the PowerShell Gallery). See https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-RFC/pull/92#issuecomment-429451171. Note that the  discussion was in the context of generally providing cmdlets that manage persisted environment variables, which also never materialized; I feel strongly that no new cmdlets are needed, and that the existing `*-Item` could be enhanced).

Comment: Too bad, because your `Update-PathVariable` proposal would have been a great specific and highly used addition to the more general (and intuitively obscure) `*-Item` *extension*, although any added functionality would have been better than the current status-quo. Extending your code above, and including an *updated* [`refreshenv`](https://github.com/badrelmers/RefrEnv/blob/main/refrenv.ps1) version will do.

Comment: Only one question, why are you using the dummy with `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($dummyName, 'foo', 'User')` after loading the update? Doesn't using `[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $SPATH, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)` trigger the same `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`?

Comment: Thanks, @not2qubit. `System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $SPATH, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)` can unfortunately NOT be used directly, because it would invariably create a `REG_SZ` value, whereas it is important to preserve a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value and entries with embedded references to other environment variables - hence the need for direct registry manipulation.

Comment: @nguyenvanbang, you can ignore the warning re `>` in `2>$null` in Visual Studio Code - it is a false positive.

Comment: @Sergio, yes, that works for me, if the script file contains the `Add-Path` function definition _before_ the `Add-Path $args[0]` call - do NOT double-quote `$args[0]` - not only is double-quoting not necessary in this case, it won't work as you expect - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50215337/45375).

Comment: Please please please make it standard!

Answer (score -2):

Use [setx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) to permanently update an environment variable.  Don't hack the registry.

After you invoke setx, just update the Path environment manually in the current session. [Powershell: Reload the path in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794507/powershell-reload-the-path-in-powershell)

Comment: I got it to work using `setx` like this: `setx PATH "$env:path;C:\Users\921479\AppData\Local\SumatraPDF"`. I guess the person who wrote that procedure I was following had basically no idea what they were talking about.

Comment: Using [`setx.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx) is tempting, but should be avoided, because `setx.exe` has fundamental limitations that make it problematic, in particular its lack of support for updating environment variables such as `Path` that are based on `REG_EXPAND_SZ`-typed registry values, and generally because values that are longer than 1024 characters are unsupported.

Comment: In retrospect. @mklement0's answer is clearly more complete.