# How to set Rust's cargo directory in windows PATH?

Tags: windows, powershell, rust

I want unnatended install of rust, so I did this little script:

```
Write-Host "Installing Rust..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$exePath = "$env:TEMP\rustup-init.exe"

Write-Host "Downloading..."
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe', $exePath)

Write-Host "Installing..."
cmd /c start /wait $exePath -y
Remove-Item $exePath

$addPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\.cargo\bin"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, $addPath)
```

but I get

```
  virtualbox-iso: Cannot convert argument "target", with value: "C:\Users\vagrant\.cargo\bin", for "SetEnvironmentVariable" to type
    virtualbox-iso: "System.EnvironmentVariableTarget": "Cannot convert value "C:\Users\vagrant\.cargo\bin" to type
    virtualbox-iso: "System.EnvironmentVariableTarget". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name C:\Users\vagrant\.cargo\bin to a valid
```

it looks like a text cannot be converted to a PATH type? What does it mean?

Comment: The third parameter to [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=net-6.0) is an enum ([`EnvironmentVariableTarget`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environmentvariabletarget?view=net-6.0)) and not a string. The function *sets* the variable value, it doesn't append to it. You have to do the appending yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *immediate* solution to your problem is that you need to call [`[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) as follows:

```bash
# Modify the user-level PATH definition.
# To modify the machine-level definition, use 'Machine' instead of user 'User',
# but you then need to run with ELEVATION (as admin).
# !! SEE CAVEATS BELOW.
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ($env:PATH + ";$addPath"), 'User')
```

That is, as [Herohtar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574531/herohtar) points out, the method expects only a complete, new value, as the second parameter, and its third parameter specifies the *target scope* for the persistent, registry-based environment-variable definition.

**Caveats**:

- The process-level `$env:PATH` value is a *composite* value of the machine-level and user-level definitions in the registry, so with the command above you're in effect *duplicating* entries from the respective other scope.
- Additionally, redefining the variable this way replaces any entries in the value that are defined in terms of *other* environment variables with the *expanded*, literal values.

  - `$env:PATH` contains *expanded* values to begin with, but even reading the unexpanded value directly from the registry won't work, because `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` *invariably* writes the given string as a `REG_SZ` value (literal string) rather than as an `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value (string that may contain `%FOO%`-style references to other environment variables). Similarly, `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()` only reports *expanded* values.

A **proper solution** requires quite a bit of extra work, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375), which contains helper function `Add-Path`.

A **pragmatic shortcut** - *if you're willing to accept that your registry definitions are converted to *literal* strings* - is the following:

- Read the current definition - for the target scope only - *from the registry*, via [`[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable)
- Add to this scope-specific value and save it back to the same scope.
- Additionally, you may want to add the new entry to the *in-process* definition of `$env:PATH` so that the change takes immediate effect.

Here is the solution in the context of a streamlined version of your code:

```bash
Write-Host "Installing Rust..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
$exePath = "$env:TEMP\rustup-init.exe"

Write-Host "Downloading..."
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/rustup-init.exe' -OutFile $exePath

Write-Host "Installing..."
& $exePath -y
Remove-Item $exePath

$addPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\.cargo\bin"
$scope = 'User' # Change to 'Machine', if needed, which then requires ELEVATION.
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(
  'PATH', 
  ([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $scope) + ";$addPath"), 
  $scope
)

# Also update the current process' definition
$env:PATH += ";$addPath"
```