# Trying to run a clojure project on emacs but Java error: Cannot run program powershell.exe

Tags: java, powershell, clojure, path-variables

I am trying to run a clojure jar file on emacs using cider and I get the error below:

```
ERROR:ERROR:  Unhandled REPL handler exception processing messageUnhandled REPL handler exception processing message  {{:op:op  init-debuggereval, , :code cljs.core/demunge, :session 9f9a0db9-8cc7-4cf0-b0ba-f426b163fb52, :id :nrepl.middleware.print/stream?7 }1
, :nrepl.middleware.print/print cider.nrepl.pprint/pprint, :nrepl.middleware.print/quota 1048576, :nrepl.middleware.print/buffer-size 4096, :nrepl.middleware.print/options {:right-margin 70}, :session 2f97cb2f-b111-4c37-8658-b63045c9ab2a, :id 6}
Syntax error macroexpanding at (clojuredocs.clj:19:32).

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have powershell route set on my env PATH both on System envs and User envs as follow:

[image]

Java version: `"20.0.1"`

I am not sure what I am missing to be able to run the command `cider-jack-in` successfully

Comment: I have a vague recollection that on some operating systems Emacs has some kind of issues with PATH. Try setting [`exec-path`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ExecPath) as well. and see if that helps.

Comment: You need the containing directory in the PATH env variable, eg. `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, not `C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Mathias you were right, I deleted the file from the path ant it finally works!! THANK YOU

Comment: OP or @MathiasR.Jessen: *Please post an answer.* Comments can be deleted at any time - they don't help users looking for such a Q and A. They're not searchable here or by googling, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

The special **`PATH`<sup>[1]</sup> environment variable** (accessible in PowerShell at the process level as `$env:PATH` - see the conceptual [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) help topic) - on both *Windows* and *Unix*-like platforms - contains **a list of (usually *absolute*) *directory* paths in which the platform APIs look for *executables* when an attempt is made to invoke an executable *by file name only*** (rather than, unambiguously, by a file *path*).

- Therefore, it is never the path of a given executable *file* itself that should be added to that list, but only ever the *directory* in which that executable is located.

**General information**:

- The *separator character* used to separate the `PATH` entries is *platform-specific*:

  - Windows uses `;`, whereas Unix-like platforms use `:`
  - To *programmatically* determine this character, use `[System.IO.Path]::PathSeparator`
- The *order* of entries matters: the *first* directory listed in which an executable of the given name is found is used.

  - Additionally, on Windows only, if a name doesn't include a *filename extension* (e.g., just `foo` instead of `foo.exe`), Windows tries the extensions listed in the special `PATHEXT` *in order* to find a matching executable (on Unix, executables usually do *not* have extensions, and if they do, they must be specified explicitly).
- PowerShell itself has *no* support for programmatically modifying the *persistent* definition of `PATH`, necessitating direct use of the [`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) .NET API:

  - However:

    - (a) This API works on *Windows only* (there is *no* unified mechanism that would work across all Unix-like platforms)
    - (b) This API *isn't robust*, because it invariably converts the `REG_EXPAND_SZ` `PATH` definition to `REG_SZ`
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375) for background information and a registry-based workaround.

---

<sup>[1] The exact case on *Windows* is `Path`, whereas on Unix-like platforms it is `PATH`. Since environment-variable access in Windows is case-*insensitive*, whereas on Unix it is case-*sensitive*, the form `PATH` works on both platforms.</sup>