# eas : The term 'eas' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program - expo

Tags: windows, npm, expo, eas, path-variables

every thing was working fine with development build until I edited some user variables mistakenly .

then all eas commands end with this error:

```
eas : The term 'eas' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ eas login
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (eas:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I've tried `npm install -g eas-cli` and `npm uninstall -g eas`

and didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it after adding these paths into system variables

1_ `C:\Users\YourPcName\AppData\Roaming\npm`
and I moved it up to the top of all other paths

2_ `C:\Users\YourPcName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\eas-cli\bin`

Answer (score 0):

Your question boils down to how to **repair the persistent definition of the `PATH` environment variable** so that **CLIs installed *globally* with `npm install -g`** can **again be invoked by *name only***, such as `eas` in your case.

To that end, make sure that the **directory path output by `npm prefix -g`** - normally `"$env:APPDATA\npm"` - is **part of the *user-level* definition of the `PATH` environment variable in the registry**.<sup>[1]</sup>

- Note: You only need to add *this one* directory - it is where entry points (`*.cmd` and `.ps1` files and Unix shell scripts) for *all* globally installed CLIs are placed.

To **automate** the process:

```bash
$globalClisDir = npm prefix -g

# Make sure the directory is listed in the *persistent, user-level* definition
# of the PATH env. var. in the registry.
if (([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -split ';' -eq $globalClisDir).Count -eq 0) { 
  # Important: Get the current definition in *unexpanded* form directly
  #            from the registry.
  $userPathRaw = 
    (Get-Item HKCU:\Environment).GetValue('Path', $null, 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
  # Update it with the directory appended.
  Set-ItemProperty HKCU:\Environment Path "$userPathRaw;$globalClisDir" 
}
```

Note:

- The updated `PATH` value will take effect in *future* PowerShell sessions, though you'll need to communicate to the Windows shell that environment variables have changed:

  - In the simplest form, force-restart all `explorer.exe` windows:

    ```bash
    Stop-Process -Name explorer
    ```
  - For a gentler approach, see the linked answer below.
- To also update it for the *current* session, run:

  ```bash
    $env:PATH+=";$(npm prefix -g)"
  ```
- The sole purpose of the `if` statement is to prevent accidentally adding the directory *multiple* times.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69239861/45375) explains why it is important to update `Path` - and other environment variables that are defined as `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry values - directly via the registry, and *not* with utilities such as `setx.exe` or the [`[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable) .NET API.

---

<sup>[1] Since globally installed npm packages are placed in a *user-specific location* (which other users generally cannot access), it makes sense to only modify the user-level `PATH` definition.</sup>